# Unsupported URL error clicking a Whatsapp scheme with an URL in a iOS WKWebView

Tags: ios, whatsapp, wkwebview

I'm using iOS 9.3.3 and clicking a Whatsapp link in a website displayed in a WKWebView.

Whenever I try to send a message to the whatsapp url scheme with a URL that includes the http:// or https:// part of the link as part of the message I get an "Unsupported URL" error.

```
 [self.webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=this%20is%20a%20test%20http://https://www.usa-brands.net/collections/new-arrivals/products/dacey-cap-sleeve-drop-waist-wool-sweater-dress"]]];
```

When I take out the http:// or https:// it works but now I don't get a Rich Preview (https://www.macstories.net/ios/whatsapp-adds-rich-previews-for-web-links/).

I've tried encoding the url but this doesn't work either. When I remove all other potential problems it comes down to the protocol in the url link.

The full error message is:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={_WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=whatsapp://send?text=Check%20this%20out%20'Dacey'%20Cap%20Sleeve%20Drop%20Waist%20Wool%20Sweater%20Dress,%20348.00%20USD:%20https://www.usa-brands.net/products/dacey-cap-sleeve-drop-waist-wool-sweater-dress, NSErrorFailingURLKey=whatsapp://send?text=Check%20this%20out%20'Dacey'%20Cap%20Sleeve%20Drop%20Waist%20Wool%20Sweater%20Dress,%20348.00%20USD:%20https://www.usa-brands.net/products/dacey-cap-sleeve-drop-waist-wool-sweater-dress, NSUnderlyingError=0x137dd1380 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=whatsapp://send?text=Check%20this%20out%20'Dacey'%20Cap%20Sleeve%20Drop%20Waist%20Wool%20Sweater%20Dress,%20348.00%20USD:%20https://www.usa-brands.net/products/dacey-cap-sleeve-drop-waist-wool-sweater-dress, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLKey=whatsapp://send?text=Check%20this%20out%20'Dacey'%20Cap%20Sleeve%20Drop%20Waist%20Wool%20Sweater%20Dress,%20348.00%20USD:%20https://www.usa-brands.net/products/dacey-cap-sleeve-drop-waist-wool-sweater-dress}}, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work. It works for Android.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement the WKWebView's WKNavigationDelegate function:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if (![url.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Sorry, you haven't install the %@", url.scheme);
        }
        decisionHandler(NO);
    }
    decisionHandler(YES);
}
```

And don't forget add whatsapp's white list at `Info.plist`:

```
<dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
    ......
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Will be invoked multiple times (depending on the website) and inside this method you will need to check the url request of the [navigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationaction), in other words, we are giving the opportunity to intercept a request before it is being send and decide if we can continue with it or not:

```
if let requestURL = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString,
     !requestURL.contains("https") && !requestURL.contains("http") {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
} else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
 }
```

If the request contains https or http it means we can safely navigate wherever we want. If not, you will have to add multiple validation like in @广锅锅 answer for example.